# Cannot run unit tests in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

When trying to run junit tests in Intellij I get an error:

> Error:java: warnings found and -Werror specified

It seems that the presence of warnings prevent my tests from running? I'm not sure how to disable that (or how it got set in the first place).

Using IntelliJ Community Edition 2018.2.5

Comment: Please provide more context in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear: this is specific to my IDE. I can download and run any Java project with JUnit tests and get the same result. I'm sure there is some relevant IntelliJ configuration I could share, but I don't know what that would be

Comment: Can you provide the steps you take to get the error? IE are you running a preset configuration/manually running tests/etc?